# Как сделать иерархию файлов, зная только путь к файлам?

Tags: php, json

Есть слудующая структура в БД:

```
> ID;name_file;file_patch;pages
> 1;11.pdf;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Документы;15
> 2;12.pdf;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Документы\Срочное;26
> 3;13.docx;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Документы\Не срочное;35
> 4;555.docx;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Приказы;88
> 5;777.docx;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Приказы;10
> 6;25.pdf;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Справки;1
> 7;54.pdf;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Справки;1
> 8;25.pdf;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Остальные доки;15
> 9;2323.docx;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Остальные доки\Картинки;25
> 10;23.pdf;C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Остальные доки\Рабочее\хлам;23
```

Соответственно, 
**ID** каждого файла - он уникальный в БД, и должен использоваться в конечном результате 
**name_file** имя файла (неуникальное имя в БД, но уникально по общему пути/ид), 
**filepatch** - сам путь, где лежит файл, 
**pages** - количество страниц в файле.
Общим является путь сканируемой папки с файлами **C:\Documents\2020.02\АК** - ее мы обрезаем, и получаем  соответствующие названия папок.
*А дальше интересное:* 
Как построить иерархию файлов, чтобы построить иерархию только лишь на основе названий директорий, с вложенностью. Т.е. Вывести название папки, указать что в ней есть перечисленные файлы(с указанием **ID** и **имени файла**) и еще какая-то директория (далее перечислить все, что находится уже в этой директории). 
Пример того, что должно получиться:

```
name:'Остальные доки',
value:{ 'flag':'icon-folder', 'id_file':'Остальные доки',},
children:[
    {
        name:'Рабочее',
        value:{'flag':'icon-folder', 'id_file':'Рабочее'},
        children:[
            {
                name:'Хлам',
                value:{ 'isTeam' : true , 'flag':'icon-folder', 'id_file':'Хлам'},
                children:[
                    {
                        name:'документ.docx',
                        value:{ 'isTeam' : true , 'flag':'icon-doc', 'id_file':'90', 'pages':125},
                        children:[]
                    },
                    {
                        name:'скан.pdf',
                        value:{ 'isTeam' : true , 'flag':'icon-pdf', 'id_file':'91', 'pages':125},
                        children:[]
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name:'Москва.pdf',
                value:{ 'isTeam' : true , 'flag':'icon-pdf', 'id_file':'98', 'pages':125},
                children:[]
            },
            {
                name:'Екатеринбург.docx',
                value:{ 'isTeam' : true , 'flag':'icon-word', 'id_file':'64', 'pages':125},
                children:[]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        name:'Картинки',
        value:{'isTeam' : true ,'flag':'icon-folder', 'id_file':'Картинки'},
        children:[
            {
                name:'Netherlands.pdf',
                value:{ 'isTeam' : true , 'flag':'icon-pdf', 'id_file':'22', 'pages':125},
                children:[]
            },
            {
                name:'Chile.pdf',
                value:{ 'isTeam' : true , 'flag':'icon-pdf', 'id_file':'42', 'pages':125},
                children:[]
                },
            ]

    }
]
```

Хранить имя родительской папки в БД (даже в отдельных таблицах) невозможно, т.к. сложность заключается в том, что структура папок может быть абсолютно любая, с любой вложенностью. Также файлы могут удалиться, и тогда производится повторное сканирование директорий. Постоянная директория только **C:\Documents\2020.02** Я произвожу только сканирование всех файлов в директориях и заношу в БД. А далее нужно построить дерево. 
Приветствую любую помощь: код/мнение/мысли...
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Судя по тегу, Вы желаете выполнить задачу именно на стороне PHP?

Comment: @Akina все верно, в MySQL лежат данные, обработка на стороне PHP и дальнейший вывод директорий/файлов в браузере. Реализация отрисовки структуры уже готова, на основе json-данных, которые привел, как пример. Вопрос именно в том, как имеющиеся данные превратить в такую структуру.

Comment: Делаете explode по \, и array_merge_recursive в одну переменную для всех записей в БД. В итоге получится что у некоторых записей будет расширение (файлы), а у остальных - нет.

Comment: Дело ваше... я бы прямо из MySQL получил нужный JSON...

Comment: @Akina принципиальной разницы нет, но к сожалению, мое знание синтаксиса MySQL очень хромает (только простейшие запросы к базе Select/update/join/и т.д. т.к. в основном у меня это делает фреймворк, и я об этом не задумываюсь). Если можете помочь, приму вашу помощь с огромной благодарностью.

Comment: Ну делайте на PHP... *мнение/мысли...* Считаете уровень каждого объекта, а потом сворачиваете в направлении уменьшения уровня, группируя по полному каталогу текущего уровня группировки.

Comment: Ваше дерево в базе — это Materialized Path. Собственно, сортируете и бежите в цикле/рекурсии. Если текущий path+'\' - префикс в следующем - значит следующий потомок текущего

Answer (score 3):

Через рекурсию как-то так, наверное. Что положить в value и тд, сам сообразишь, просто передай доп параметром в процедуру то, что тебе необходимо. **Нетривиальная** задачка кстати :)

```
    <?php

    function getTree(&$array, $str) {

   $tmp = explode('/', $str);

    //стучимся в дно рекурсии, когда в последнем каталоге нет разделителей
    if($tmp[0] === $str) {
        $array[] = ['name' => $str,
                    'value' => '???',
                    'children' => []];
        return true;//конец
    }
    //иначе путь долгий(нет). Для начала проверяем существование обрабатываемой директории 
    else {
        
        $folder = $tmp[0];//первый фолдер в строке, который нам нужен
        $str = str_replace($folder . '/', '', $str); //оставшиеся кусок строки
        
        foreach($array as $index => $child) {
            
                //Мы ее нашли?! Плюхаемся в нее без всякого создания и сомнений
                if($child['name'] == $folder) { 
                    getTree($array[$index]['children'], $str);
                    return true;//еще один конец
                }
        }
            
        
    }
    
    //Все варианты исчерпали, то просто создаем каталог
    $array[] = ['name' => $folder,
                'value' => '???',
                'children' => []];
                        
    getTree($array[array_key_last($array)]['children'], $str);
}



//собственно сам массив, на выходе древовидного формата,джейсонь его сколько хочешь
$array = ['name' => 'C:/Documents/2020.02/AK/',
          'value' => '',
          'children' => []
         ];


//здесь у тебя плюс минус ориентировочные рекорды, которые ты с базы получаешь после предварительной обработки 
$queryMySQL = ['Document/pupsik',
               'Document/mir/voda/stalin',
               'Images/mir/blyat/domik'];

//бежим по рекордам
foreach ($queryMySQL as $str) {
    getTree($array['children'],$str);
}

var_dump($array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно и без рекурсии обойтись, но с небольшой ссылочной магией

```php
<?php

// Выборка из БД
$rows = getRows();

// Длина обрезки
$remove = mb_strlen('C:\Documents\2020.02\\');

// Результат
$result = [];

// Ссылки на подкаталоги
$links = [];

// Обходим массив
foreach ($rows as $row) {

    // Ссылаемся на корень результирующего массива
    $current = &$result;

    // Обрезаем путь
    $path = mb_substr($row['file_patch'], $remove);

    // Обходим папки пути
    foreach (explode('\\', $path) as $dir) {

        /*
         * Если нужной папки нет в результирующем массиве, добавляем.
         * Для удобства навигации в качестве ключа будем использовать
         * имя папки
         */
        if (!array_key_exists($dir, $current)) {
            $current[$dir] = [
                'name' => $dir,
                'value' => [
                    'flag' => 'icon-folder',
                    'id_file' => $dir,
                ],
                'children' => [],
            ];
        }

        // Добавляем ссылку, чтобы потом ассоциативный массив преобразовать в обычный
        $links[] = &$current[$dir];

        // Меняем ссылку на нижний уровень для следующей итерации
        $current = &$current[$dir]['children'];
    }

    // добавляем в конечную папку файлик
    $current[] = [
        'name' => $row['name_file'],
        'value' => [
            'isTeam' => true,
            'flag' => 'icon-' . pathinfo($row['name_file'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION),
            'id_file' => $row['ID'],
            'pages' => $row['pages'],
        ],
        'children' => [],
    ];
}

// Проходим по нашим ссылкам и преобразуем их в обычные массивы
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $link['children'] = array_values($link['children']);
}

// очищаем указатели ссылки и массив ссылок
unset($current, $link, $links);

// преобразуем результирующий массив в обычный
$result = array_values($result);

// готово
print_r($result);

function getRows()
{
    return [
        [
            'ID' => 1,
            'name_file' => '11.pdf',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Документы',
            'pages' => 15,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 2,
            'name_file' => '12.pdf',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Документы\Срочное',
            'pages' => 26,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 3,
            'name_file' => '13.docx',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Документы\Не срочное',
            'pages' => 35,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 4,
            'name_file' => '555.docx',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Приказы',
            'pages' => 88,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 5,
            'name_file' => '777.docx',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Приказы',
            'pages' => 10,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 6,
            'name_file' => '25.pdf',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Справки',
            'pages' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 7,
            'name_file' => '54.pdf',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Справки',
            'pages' => 1,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 8,
            'name_file' => '25.pdf',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Остальные доки',
            'pages' => 15,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 9,
            'name_file' => '2323.docx',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Остальные доки\Картинки',
            'pages' => 25,
        ],
        [
            'ID' => 10,
            'name_file' => '23.pdf',
            'file_patch' => 'C:\Documents\2020.02\АК\Остальные доки\Рабочее\хлам',
            'pages' => 23,
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Небольшую поправочку предложу к обоим методам - насколько я вижу из приведенного примера автора там узлами дерева являются объекты, а вот дети уже массивами. Но, я думаю, автор вопроса легко переделает выбранное решение под себя.